# Why doesn't run on idempotent mode my LWRPs?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, lwrp

It is my `action :create` of my custom LWRP, but it always run. I want to make an  idempotent action.

Here is my implementation:

```
action :create do
  converge_by "Create [#{@new_resource}]" do

    USER_NAME     = @new_resource.username
    USER_PASSWORD = @new_resource.password unless (@new_resource.password.nil? ||
                                                        @new_resource.password.empty?)
    USER_PASSWORD = USER_NAME
    DATABASE_NAME = @new_resource.database_name unless (@new_resource.database_name.nil? ||
                                                              @new_resource.database_name.empty?)
    DATABASE_NAME = USER_NAME

    execute "create user [#{USER_NAME}]" do
      user "postgres"
      exists = <<-EOH
      PGPASSWORD='postgres' psql -U postgres -c "select * from pg_user where usename='#{USER_NAME}'" | grep -c #{USER_NAME}
      EOH
      command "PGPASSWORD='postgres' createuser -U postgres -sw #{USER_NAME}"
      not_if exists, :user => "postgres"
    end

    execute "set-password" do
      user "postgres"
      command "PGPASSWORD='postgres' psql -U postgres -c \"alter role #{USER_NAME} with password '#{USER_PASSWORD}'\""
    end

    execute "create-database" do
      user "postgres"
      exists = <<-EOH
      PGPASSWORD='postgres' psql -U postgres -c "select * from pg_database WHERE datname='#{DATABASE_NAME}'" | grep -c #{DATABASE_NAME}
      EOH
      command "PGPASSWORD='postgres' createdb -U postgres -O #{USER_NAME} -T template0 #{DATABASE_NAME}"
      not_if exists, :user => "postgres"
    end
  end
  @new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)
end
```

Why doesn't works the last line `@new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)`?

Comment: updated_by_last_action isn't used when you use `converge_by`

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have a direct answer to your question, you may be interested in ToASTER, a framework for testing idempotence of Chef scripts.

http://cloud-toaster.github.io/

Chef recipes are executed with different configurations in isolated container environments (Docker VMs), and ToASTER reports various metrics such as system state changes, convergence properties, and idempotence issues.